# Will there be a sequel to "Ex Machina"?

Tags: sequels, ex-machina

I found "Ex Machina" to be well done AND intriguing. What will the robot do now that she is loose in human society?  Which will develop quickest her sense of survival, a new sense of compassion, will she ever deal with a sense of fair play and how about a need to be among her own kind.

So! Will there be a sequel to deal with these questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to the director, Alex Garland, the answer would be: **no**](http://deadline.com/2015/05/ex-machina-alex-garland-2000-screens-no-sequel-1201421795/)

> “I imagined it as a completely self-contained story and I still feel that way about it,” Garland said. “It has become reflexive for people to imagine this movie was made to set up a sequel and that the plan was built into the structure of the film. But it was not that way, at all.”